# xcolor's \cellcolor offsets alignment of text in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, color

I have multiple tables in a document using xcolor's `\cellcolor` command but it offsets the text by a small amount so it is not centered correctly. `\rowcolor` does not exhibit the same behaviour. It looks as it does here:

[image: 4 row table showing cell 2 offset to the right by the \cellcolor command]

Does anyone know why this is and how it might be solved globally?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
                          Centred \\ \hline
        \cellcolor{white} Centred \\ \hline
                          Centred \\ \hline
        \rowcolor{white}  Centred
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the space between `\cellcolor` and the following text, the alignment is as expected:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
                          Centred \\ \hline
        \cellcolor{white}Centred \\ \hline
                          Centred \\ \hline
        \rowcolor{white}  Centred
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has been giving me a headache for a while and it's an extra space causing it. Hahaha. Thank you very much.